# Convert Get-ADUser to Get-PnPAzureADUser

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We have the following Power shell code which connect to onpremsies AD:-

```
$HiringManger = Get-ADUser -Filter  {enabled -eq $True -and mail -eq test@***.com } -SearchBase "OU=Sites,dc=company-tech,dc=net"
```

and we want to convert `Get-ADUser` to `Get-PnPAzureADUser` . But when i tried the following i got this error:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $HRUser = Get-PnPAzureADUser -Filter  {AccountEnabled -eq $True -and Mail -eq test@***.com } -SearchBase "OU=Sites,dc=comapny-tech,dc=net"

Get-PnPAzureADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SearchBase'.
At line:1 char:114
+ ...  -and Mail -eq test@***.com } -SearchBase "OU=Sit ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-PnPAzureADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Principals.GetAzureADUser
```

Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `Get-PnPAzureADUser` doesn't have a `-SearchBase` parameter (see [Documentation](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPAzureADUser.html))

Longer answer: In Azure, there is *no concept* of OU's. Everything is flat. Therefore there is no need for `-SearchBase` because there are no OU's to filter/sort/group by.

Comment: thansk a lot for the valuable reply